# How does the ternary operator compares characters and numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement, conditional-operator

I had to find maximum in array so I wrote a function which used for loop while also using ternary operator and I noticed that just reversing the direction of loop changes the output plus the output is also different if I use if-else. Moreover, changing the position of  'a' in the array also changes the output.

```js
const array2 = ['a', 3, 4, 2];

function biggestNumberInArray(arr) {
    let max=0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      max = max>arr[i]?max:arr[i];
    }
    return max;
}

function biggestNumberInArray2(arr) {
    let max=0;
    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      max = max>arr[i]?max:arr[i];
    }
    return max;
}

console.log(biggestNumberInArray(array2));
console.log(biggestNumberInArray2(array2));
```

When running the first function output is 4

When running the second function output is 'a'

Comment: Q: Have you stepped through a debugger to see at what point "max" is incorrectly being changed to the wrong number?

Comment: @Shivansh and what do you think `'a'` converts to when compared to a number?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I think it would change to its ASCII value i.e. 97

Comment: @Shivansh well that's where you'd be wrong.

Comment: Interestingly, `4 > 'a'`, `4 < 'a'` and `4 == 'a'` all are false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you step through the debugger and look at the comparisions ... you'll see that comparing 'a' with *any* number is *always* false.

That's why it seems to "work" in one direction, but not the other.

Specifically:

> When comparing a string with a number, JavaScript will convert the
>   string to a number when doing the comparison. An empty string converts
>   to 0. A non-numeric string converts to NaN which is always false .
>   When comparing two strings, "2" will be greater than "12", because
>   (alphabetically) 1 is less than 2.

Comment: Please properly [cite your quote](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp).

Comment: Interesting thing about `NaN` is that it is not even equal to itself `NaN == NaN` false.

Answer (score 1):

Because string `'a'` and integers `2,3,4` are incomparable. Therefore it always returns `false`

In your first function, it returns `4` because `'a'` is compared first and returns `false`, then `max` is assigned `3`

In the second function it returns `'a'` because `'a'` is compared last.

You can check if the string can be converted to number using `Number()` or `parseInt()`

```js
const arr = ['a', 3, 4, 2];

function biggestNumberInArray2(arr) {
    let max=0;
    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      const comparable = Number(arr[i]) || -99
      max = max > comparable ? max : comparable;
    }
    return max;
}

console.log(biggestNumberInArray2(arr))
```

Comment: Nice, but I think all of this could be avoided if we filter out strings from arr in the first place like `arr.filter(parseFloat)`

Comment: Yes it can be improved as you said. I just wanted to explain why the second function returns `'a'` instead of `4`

Comment: Agreed. I always go for "_precaution is better than cure_" path whenever possible.